# Add all the columns of a consult in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a table with columns

```
[a1,a2,a3,a4,a5....an]
```

all the values are numeric. And I'd like a consult that returns:

```
 [a1,a2,a3,a4,a5....an, S]
```

Where S= a1+a2+a3+...+an

Is possible to do that without specify the column names in the S calculation? (for don't change that part if some column is added or removed)

Anyway whats the best solution I can use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a1, a2, a3, ... , an, (a1 + a2 + ... + an) AS S FROM yourColumn.
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to omit naming all the columns.  Also, you are working against how relational databases are intended to be used.

Instead create a table which has metacolumns, for example:

```
CREATE TABLE `tableA` (
 `id`           int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `col_index`    int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 `value`        int NOT NULL,
  ...
);
```

To retrieve the equivalent of `a5`:

```
SELECT value
 FROM `tableA`
 WHERE col_index = 5  AND (whatever selects the proper rows)
```